# Password strength JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can you help me find out why my code isn't working?
I have to chceck if password is 
a)4-6 characters long (one or more numbers must be included) for password to be medium
b)7 and more characters (one or more numbers must be included) for strong. c)Anything else than a) and b) is weak.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pl">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>    

    <form>
        <p>
            <input type="password" id="password" />
            <button onlick="spr()">check</button>
        </p>
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>     

    <script>
    function spr()
    {
        var str = document.getElementById("password");
        var medium = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,6}$/;
        var strong = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{7,}$/;

        if(medium.test(str))
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="medium";
        else if(silne.test(str))
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="strong";
        else
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="weak";

        return false;
    }   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some advice - you should be sure to re-validate these password constraints on your server side. It would be very easy for an "evil user" to bypass these client side checks.

Comment: It's only for school project use

Comment: There are evil students too ;) All I'm saying is that any sort of security checks that one does on the client side can be modified by any user who knows how to use the chrome dev tools.

Comment: It is a good idea to get used to practicing good security even if it is for a school project. Perhaps all you need in this case is a comment (for the teacher to read) mentioning the limitation of client side checks such as these.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working in the code? One error seems to be that `silne` is not defined.

Comment: *my code isn't working* Is not working in what way, precisely? Console error? Unexpected behavior? Also, your regexp will not enforce the requirement that there be at least one number in the password.

Comment: onlick - nice...but typo...   var str = document.getElementById("password") - you don't need element, you need its value, etc...

Comment: @Lix I know about that but this is a part of an exam of qualifications in my country and I have to do it as they say. And I don't know why I don't get any relut from this code :(

Comment: @Matias513, few typos fixed, and other mentioned problems fixed, BUT: https://jsfiddle.net/3ae9yqx6/ your regex must be changed, too ;)

Comment: fwiw, these kind of rules make passwords much easier to crack...

Answer (score 0):

follow this https://jsfiddle.net/umesh1990/hxjf74cz/35/#
i have done this using javascript

```js
function password_validate(txt) {
  var val1 = 0;
  var val2 = 0;
  var val3 = 0;
  var val4 = 0;
  var val5 = 0;
  var counter, color, result;
  var flag = false;
  if (txt.value.length <= 0) {
    counter = 0;
    color = "transparent";
    result = "";
  }
  if (txt.value.length < 8 & txt.value.length > 0) {
    counter = 20;
    color = "red";
    result = "Short";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(txt.id + "error").innerHTML = " ";
    txt.style.borderColor = "grey";
    var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;
    //  document.getElementById("pass_veri").style.display="block";
    var fletter = /[a-z]/;
    if (fletter.test(txt.value)) {
      val1 = 20;

    } else {
      val1 = 0;
    }
    //macth special character
    var special_char = /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/;
    if (special_char.test(txt.value)) {
      val2 = 30;
    } else {
      val = 0;
    }
    /*capital_letter*/
    var cap_lett = /[A-Z]/;
    if (cap_lett.test(txt.value)) {
      val3 = 20;
    } else {
      val = 0;
    }
    /*one numeric*/
    var num = /[0-9]/;
    if (num.test(txt.value)) {
      val4 = 20;
    } else {
      val4 = 0;
    }
    /* 8-15 character*/
    var range = /^.{8,50}$/;
    if (range.test(txt.value)) {
      val5 = 10;
    } else {
      val5 = 0;
    }
    counter = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5;

    if (counter >= 30) {
      color = "skyblue";
      result = "Fair";
    }
    if (counter >= 50) {
      color = "gold";
      result = "Good";
    }
    if (counter >= 80) {
      color = "green";
      result = "Strong";
    }
    if (counter >= 90) {
      color = "green";
      result = "Very Strong";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("prog").style.width = counter + "%";
  document.getElementById("prog").style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById("result").style.color = color;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
}


/* tooltip*/

.hint {
  width: 258px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #CC9933;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.hint:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 24px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #CC9933;
}

.hint:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 26px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #FFFFCC;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.progress {
  height: 7px;
}

#progres {
  display: block;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.form-control {
  width: none;
  margin-left: 260px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 parent ">
  <label class="hint" id="pass-hint">
    Password Strength:<span id="result"></span>
    <br>
    <div class="progress" id="progres">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" id="prog">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p> passowrd must have atleast 8 charatcer</p>
  </label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="pass" onfocus="document.getElementById('pass-hint').style.display='block'" onblur="document.getElementById('pass-hint').style.display='none'" placeholder="**********"
    oninput="password_validate(this);document.getElementById('progres').style.display='block';">
  <i class=" form-control-feedback" id="passsuccess" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span id="passerror" class="help-block error"></span>
</div>
```

it may help you